# Flutter Device Selection stuck at Loading... in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have issue with flutter device selection, it stucks at Loading... I can expand this selection but everytime is only possible option such as `Open Andorid Emulator: {...}` when I click on it, it appears:

```
INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.21.0 (build_id 11009868) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\ [11292:10984:20231117,085610.488:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.21.db\attachments\29a4c8fc-f8a5-450f-923a-b2b887559972: Nie moĹĽna odnaleĹşÄ‡ okreĹ›lonego pliku. (2) [11292:10984:20231117,085610.488:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.21.db\attachments\abaa2978-3250-4094-844e-c6ae4f55757b: Nie moĹĽna odnaleĹşÄ‡ okreĹ›lonego pliku. (2) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88d5:8846:7d02:0:309f:8846:7d02:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 8572 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO |
```

I try every possible way to deal with this like:

- reset PC
- change location sdk folder from c:\flutter to d:\flutter
- change android studio version
- change sdk version older, newer
- change API version
- change Virtual Devices, Wipe Data, Cold boot now,
- connect with phisical device, Andorid studio recognizes it but there is no option to select it in `Flutter Device Selection`
- compare with team mate, he lunches it easily with the same version of SDK (3.7.9) and android studio (I was thinking that maybe company firewall or antivir stop it)
- when I create new flutter project it stucks on Loading... as well
- when I run main() it shows: "No connected devices found..."
- reset adb (adb kill-server, adb start-server)
- delete sdk platform-tools folder and download new
- File -> Invalidate Cache/ Restart
- I tried to run the project in Visual Studio Code with the Flutter plugin, but I also got stuck, nothing happened
- when I run 'taskkill /F /IM dart.exe' then 'flutter run' , after a few seconds andorid alert appears: "Flutter Device Daemon Crash, The flutter device daemon cannot be started. Please check your configuration and restart the IDE. You may need to increase the maximum number of file handles available globally."
- flutter doctor -v:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel @upstream, 3.7.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570], locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 3.7.9 on channel @upstream at D:\flutter
    ! Unknown upstream repository.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    • Framework revision 62bd79521d (8 months ago), 2023-03-30 10:59:36 -0700
    • Engine revision ec975089ac
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.6)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.7.34221.43
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.9225.16
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.118
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.58

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Edit:

```
flutter devices
4 connected devices:

sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]
Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.118
Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.58
```

Comment: what's the output of `flutter devices` run in the command line?

Comment: I've edited post

Comment: and now what you see if you run `flutter run -d emulator-5554`? does it say something more than when run from the android studio?

Comment: When I launch `flutter run -d emulator-5554` project runs and works properly. Flutter device selection is still with Loading...

Comment: @pskink is it possible to run emulator this way with debug mode? I put breakpoints but app doesn't stop on it.

Comment: I don't know, while I always use `flutter run` from the command line I used VSCode debug session maybe three times or so... (good, old `print(...)` always saves my life)